# NFSv4 client not seeing file delete

Tags: linux, nfs, mount

I am using RHEL and NFSv4 client/server. The client sees modifications to files in the mounted server directory, and can read and write to those files (updates occur almost instantly). However, when you delete a file on the server, the client still shows that the file exists (even after an hour). One time, I'm not sure why, the file did disappear from the "ls" listing on the client after about 10 minutes.

SERVER:
/etc/exports file: 10.255.0.XX/255.255.255.0(rw,sync)

CLIENT:
/etc/fstab file: 10.255.0.XX: nfs noac,lookupcache=none 0 2

I tried following tips to disable caching in an attempt to always see the most recent updates to resolve this (didn't help). I've used NFS debugging to monitor the process, but no obvious errors. The epoch time stamp when I deleted the file on the server is correct when looking at the debug log on the client (decode_attr_time_modify: mtime=1561558456).

Any help would be GREATLY appreciated!

Comment: What is the client version, server version, and platform for both?

Comment: RHEL 2.6.32-696 is the OS of both the client and server, and both client and server are using NFSv4.